# Undefined Index PHP

Tags: php, html, indexing, undefined

I've done some searching but can't seem to work out the answer. I'm new to PHP.

Here is my HTML form;

```
  <form id = "getGame" action="Form.php" method = "get">
    <label> Serial 
      <input type = "search" name = "serial" />
    </label>
    <label> Title
      <input type = "search" name = "title" />
    </label>
    <label> Year
      <select name="gameYear">
        <option value="1998">1998</option>
        <option value="1999">1999</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    <label> Price
      <input type = "search" name = "price" />
    </label>
    <input type = "submit" name="search" value = "Search">
  </form>
```

Here is my PHP page;

```
include 'db_Conn.php';
$gameYear = $_GET ['gameYear'];
$sql = "SELECT serialNo, gameTitle, gameYear gamePrice FROM games  WHERE gameYear = '$gameYear'";
$Games = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) 
or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Games)) {
    $serial = $row['serialNo'];
    $title = $row['gameTitle'];
    $gameYear = $row['gameYear'];
    $gamePrice = $row['gamePrice'];     
    echo "<div>$serial, $title, $gameYear, $gamePrice</div>\n";
}

mysqli_free_result($Books); 
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

My problem is when I run the form I get the following message "Notice: Undefined index: gameYear". However, on the line below it displays all the records from the game year I selected. Example of what displays below;

```
Notice: Undefined index: gameYear in ____ on line 40
493928, Test Drive, 2002, $12.95
```

Thanks, any point in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: You are missing a comma after gameYear in your SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed one `,`. Change it to:

```
$sql = "SELECT serialNo, gameTitle, gameYear, gamePrice FROM games  WHERE gameYear = '$gameYear'";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was driving me crazy. I must remember to scan over everything more carefully in future. Once again thank you, it's much appreciated.

Comment: @RonaIdo, if Ali answered your question, please mark it accordingly, try to play nice with stackoverflow rules :-)

Comment: @mTorres I have, it wouldn't let me initially as I had to wait a certain time period for more answers.

Answer (score 0):

if no data found in the database it will produce 4 errors . so first of all check any data found or not by mysqli_num_rows() function.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($Games) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Games)) {
        $serial = $row['serialNo'];
        $title = $row['gameTitle'];
        $gameYear = $row['gameYear'];
        $gamePrice = $row['gamePrice'];
        echo "<div>$serial, $title, $gameYear, $gamePrice</div>\n";
    }
}
```

Yes of course you  missed one comma so sql should be like this

```
$sql = "SELECT serialNo, gameTitle, gameYear, gamePrice FROM games  WHERE gameYear = '$gameYear'";
```